# What is the actual reason for putting onload before send in AJAX

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS and was learning XHR AJAX. What really confuses me is that why on earth we have to put onload before we send request. I think it is logical to put onload after we send request. Just how can we do something with retrived data if we haven't sent the request yet. Here is the example code:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(),
  method = 'GET',
  url = 'https://developer.mozilla.org/';

xmlhttp.open(method, url, true);
xmlhttp.onload = function () {
  // Do something with the retrieved data ( found in xmlhttp.response )
};
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: By setting onload to a function you are just saying what code to run after the send has taken place, you aren't actually running that code before the send.

Comment: onload is an event handler. You supply it with a function that will run when the event occurs. Logically you want to set it first, to avoid a race condition of the load running before you actually bind an event to it, however that's not *really* a problem with xhr requests (or any other properly implemented async logic), you safely can bind it before or after.

Comment: @takendarkk, ok I got it but why to put onload code before send. Is it ok if I put after send?

Comment: Why don't you just try that and see what happens?

Comment: There were some really old browsers (I don't remember which but probably something like IE5) where setting the event handler after send caused it not to be triggered when send completes. But it's not really something you should worry about now.

Comment: @KevinB, Kevin thank you for your kind comments, Logically you want to set it first please can you briefly explain in an easier way the logic of why set onload first. Please only logic in a simple way. I really hope for your reply

Comment: @user11807902 As slebetman mentioned, there are (or were) some cases where a browser would immediately trigger a callback synchronously, which would in turn not trigger any callbacks that were attached *after* the action. That doesn't really happen anymore in modern browsers, but it's a safe practice to keep. For example, recently you could have a case where if you bound an image load event *after* you set the src, if the image was cached, the load event would never trigger. (that has been fixed in all modern browsers)

Comment: Those sorts of problems have largely been resolved by modern browsers, but it doesn't hurt to code defensively. There's literally no cost, and would prevent an issue if that problem ever came back or someone with an old as dirt browser managed to visit.

Answer (score 2):

send() is by default asynchronous and onload is a callback function which will be executed once you get a response from your request, not before.